# Converting Temporary table code to CTE to improve performance

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code in my Stored procedure:

```
CREATE MyProc
AS


CREATE TABLE #Table1 
(    
 Field1 INT NOT NULL,
 Field2 VARCHAR NULL,
 Field3 VARCHAR NULL,
 Field4 VARCHAR NULL

 );
```

-----Populate Temporary Table-----

```
INSERT INTO #Table1  (Field1)          
SELECT val1 FROM Tab1

INSERT INTO #Table1  (Field1,Field2)          
SELECT val1,"val2"  FROM Tab2

INSERT INTO #Table1  (Field1,Field2,Field3)          
SELECT val1,"val2","val3"  FROM Tab3

INSERT INTO #Table1  (Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4)          
SELECT val1,"val2","val3","val4"  FROM Tab3

SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4 FROM #Table1 
DROP #Table1
```

There are around 10-15 INSERT statements which are populating the temporary table.I want to tune the stored proc to improve performance using CTE or some other way.How I can rewrite the procedure?

Comment: Why do you think a CTE will improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely sure this is going to be better in any way but this is using a cte to get the same output (i used some lazy-ass value arrays to get it to work out of the box, you can ofcourse substitute those with actual tables):

```
with cte (f1, f2, f3, f4)
as (
    select 1, null, null, null
    from (
        values (1)
        ) t1(n1)

    union all

    select 1, 2, null, null
    from (
        values (1, 2)
        ) t1(n1, n2)

    union all

    select 1, 2, 3, null
    from (
        values (1, 2, 3)
        ) t1(n1, n2, n3)

    union all

    select 1, 2, 3, 4
    from (
        values (1, 2, 3, 4)
        ) t1(n1, n2, n3, n4)
    )
select *
from cte
```

Comment: I am also thinking in that way but I have a concern. Does too much Union All hit performance?

Comment: That is not something I (nor anyone else for that matter) can answer without knowing lots of intimate details of your setup and usage. My advice, test it. the proof ofthe pudding is in the eating ;) When testing always be carefull not to break stuff that works!